# How to detect the event when device is locked?

Tags: android

In my code I am trying to understand the intents that get launched when the device is locked.

Eg: Suppose my activity is running, and I press the power button to lock the phone. INTENT.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF is launched. The activity is paused and the screen goes blank.

So what i want is whenever the device is locked by the user i dont want to finish my activity, but if the user press home button or back button i am finishing the activity. So for that i have written a code but its not working.

**Code i have used**

```
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    m_ScreenLocked = false;

    // Intent and receiver to listen to screen lock
    m_IntentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    m_IntentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    m_BroadcastReceiver = new ScreenStateBroadcastReceiver();
    registerReceiver(m_BroadcastReceiver, m_IntentFilter);
}

private final class ScreenStateBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) 
    {
         if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) 
         {
            m_ScreenLocked = true;
         } 
         else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) 
         {
             //other stuff
         }
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    m_NoteManagerObject.setPageViewRunning(false);

    if (!m_ScreenLocked)
    {
         unregisterReceiver(m_BroadcastReceiver);
         finish();
     }
     else
     {
         unregisterReceiver(m_BroadcastReceiver);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you register a receiver programmtically in your activity, it won't get broadcasts when your activity is paused. the docs are fuzzy here as they simply "recommend" unregistering in `onPause()`, but do not say that the receiver won't work when your activity is paused.

the real question however is why you want to do that. as a user, i'd be miffed if my screen went off when i was using your app, and when i unlocked the screen, the app was gone. remember that you can't differentiate between the user pressing the power button and the screen simply timing out.

anyway, a possible fix is to register your activity to receive those actions in your manifest. that won't necessarily work though as not all intents can be registered for in a manifest intent filter. if i recall, the ACTION_SCREEN_* intents can't be registered for in your manifest.

another way would be to listen for those intents in a service that is running along side your activity, then be able to send a different intent to your activity to tell it to finish itself.